# How should I do a loop a nokogiri search in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, refactoring, loops, nokogiri

I have the following that I retreive the title of each url from an array that contains a list of urls.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

@urls = ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://rubyonrails.org"]

@found_titles = Array.new
@found_titles[0] = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{@urls[0]}")).search("title").inner_html

#this can go on forever...but
#@found_titles[1] = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{@urls[1]}")).search("title").inner_html
#@found_titles[2] = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{@urls[2]}")).search("title").inner_html

puts "#{@found_titles[0]}"
```

How should i form a loop method for this so i can get the title even when the list in @url array gets longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [map (or collect) method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003127):

```
@found_titles = @urls.map {|url| Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).search("title").inner_html }
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt help, Greg Campell. This is exactly what I'm looking for.